# Android: NullPointerException when trying to access a TextView from other class

Tags: java, android, gps, android-context

i'm trying to learn android development at the moment. Now i have problem i can't find a solution.

The app should get the gps position and write the coordinates in a textview.

But when the gps get's a signal i get a NullPointerException.

The following code is from my MainActitvity. GetLocation is my class to get the gps coordinates.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    GetLocation getMyLocation = new GetLocation();

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, getMyLocation);

}
```

And this is a the part from my GetLocation class where the error occures. The error occures in the line with findViewById

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    String myLocation = location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude();

    viewToChange = (TextView) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.my_position);
    viewToChange.setText("Position " + myLocation);
}
```

I think i can't access to the layout from the mainactivity in my GetLocation class... :/

UPDATE:

```
public class GetLocation implements LocationListener {
TextView viewToChange;
private Activity activity;

private void onCreate(){
}

public void GetLocation(Activity _activity){
    this.activity = _activity;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    String myLocation = location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude();

    viewToChange = (TextView) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.my_position);
    viewToChange.setText("Position " + myLocation);
}
```

Comment: where is your GetLocation ?

Comment: please post your Stack Trace.

Comment: If `GetLocation` is inner class of `MainActivity`, try change `this.activity` to `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Please show us your `activity_main.xml` layout.  Is there a `android:id="@+id/my_position`" on the `TextView` you try to fill?

Comment: Yes there is a android:id="@+id/my_position" in the activity_main.xml :)

`<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_position"
        android:text="MyPosition" />`

Comment: I added the GetLocation class above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess removing "this" on "this.activity.findViewById" will solve your problem. Create a global activity and initilize it on your constructor and use it without "this".

I can also suggest you more effective ways of customizing views from other classes:

Making view public static is an option:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

public static TextView textViewToChange;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewToChange);

    }
}
```

And in your GetLocation class you can reach it by:

```
MainActivity.textViewToChange.setText("someText");
```

You can pass the view to GetLocation via constructor:

```
public GetLocation(TextView view){
    //create a global variable and store
    this.view = view
}
```

And change its text it on onLocationChanged method.

You can also create an interface and make your MainActivity implement it, and trigger it from GetLocation when you make changes:

Interface:

```
public interface FooChangeListener {

    void onFooChange(String text);

}
```

Your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FooChangeListener {

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFooChange(String text) {
        tv.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Crate a global FooChangeListener in your GetLocation class and on your GetLocation constructor:

```
public GetLocation(FooChangeListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And in your onLocationChanged:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    location.getLatitude();
    location.getLongitude();

    String myLocation = location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude();

    listener.onFooChange(myLocation);
```

}

These are what i can suggest, hope it helps !

Comment: Yeah that's it. Now it is working. I used the way by making the view public. Thank a thousend times :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the `NullPointerException` is happening here:

```
viewToChange = (TextView) this.activity.findViewById(R.id.my_position);
```

It is `activity` that is `null`, not `viewToChange`. Make sure you have passed the `activity` object in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no standard way to retrieve your Activity from another class. You could (choose one):

- Pass the TextView to your method.
- Make your method return the String and set your TextView on your main activity.
- Pass the context to your class Constructor and retrieve your activity properly
- Pass your activity with an intent.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to pinpoint the problem if you don't provide the code of the classes and the stacktrace. I'm guessing since `this.activity` is syntactically correct in your `GetLocation` class, it's having the activity as an attribute. Make sure this activity variable is not null and activity has its content set.

Comment: i added the GetLocation Class in my first post.